# Does anyone have the ability to create an account with my key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

EDIT : tried the authorized domain and it seems to be what i need, i'll try to go deeper with André's answer :)
Thank you !

Hi,

I'm new to firebase and i just finished a project but i had a question:

Since the doc says i have to put my api keys and else in the javascript, they are visible to anyone even if put into process.env

i've read here : [Is it safe to expose Firebase apiKey to the public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public)

that making the api key public is normal and not a big deal.

I'm using the email/password auth and i'm scared

If someone takes my :

- API_KEY_FIREBASE
- AUTH_DOMAIN
- DB_URL
- PROJECT_ID

that are in the source code and use the createAccount function, is he gonna be able to create an account ?
Is yes, is there a way to disable this ?
I want to be able to create account only through the firebase console

I'm not using firebase database for my data, i only use it for auth so i don't have to create a user table in my database, but i use the IDTokens they provide to secure some routes on express.

thank you ! :)

Comment: Someone can only create an account when you have that option enabled in your firebase console. So If you have it disabled there is no problem.

Comment: How can we disable it ? can't find anything about disabling creation of new accounts :(

Comment: You can look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) in the before you begin section for how to enable/disable  Email/password sign-in method

Comment: alright thank you !

Comment: Sounds like an answer @AndréKool! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Someone can only create an account when you have that option enabled in your firebase console. So If you have it disabled there is no problem.

You can look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) in the "before you begin" section for how to enable/disable Email/password sign-in method.